# Running npm scripts conditionally

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have 2 main build configurations - dev and prod. 
I push updates to a heroku server that run npm install --production to install my app.
In the package.json I have the following segment:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "make install"
}
```

that runs a make file that is responsible for uglifying the code and some other minor things.

However, I don't need to run this makefile in development mode. Is there any way to conditionally run scripts with npm?..

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can have something like this defined in your `package.json` (I'm sure theres a better shorthand for the `if` statement.)

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall":"if test \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"production\" ; then make install ; fi "
}
```

Then when you execute `npm` with production flag like you stated you already do

```
npm install --production
```

it will execute your `make install` because it will set `$NODE_ENV = production`

---

When I need to conditionally execute some task(s), I pass environment variables to the script/program and which takes care of that logic.  I execute my scripts like this

```
NODE_ENV=dev npm run build
```

and in `package.json`, you would start a script/program

```
"scripts": {
    "build":"node runner.js"
}
```

which would check the value of the environment variable to determine what to do.  In `runner.js` I do something like the following

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV){
  switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: As you note, can also do the conditional a bit more succinctly: "postinstall": "if [ test = \"production\" ]; then make install; fi"

Comment: is that cross platform?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper no it would not be compatible with windows dos.  It would have to be adjusted accordingly to the platform the npm script is to run on. DOS has conditionals as well.

Comment: Hi, James, where is the documentation for this conditionally task because i can't find them, i need to do something like this     "postinstall":"if test \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"production\" ; then --env=prod ; else --env=qa fi " where i choose between prod and qa

Comment: @Milo the conditional is just bash conditional expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i realize that some time after... :P I'm using a script d

Answer (score 15):

For conditional npm scripts, you can use cross-platform basic logical operators to create if-like statements  ( `||` and `&&` ).
I've run into needing to run scripts to only generate helpers once on any machine. You can use inline javascript to do this by using `process.exit()` codes.

```json
"scripts": {
    "build":"(node -e \"if (! require('fs').existsSync('./bin/helpers')){process.exit(1)} \" || npm run setup-helpers) && npm run final-build-step"
}
```

So for testing `env`s you might do:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build":"node -e \"if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){process.exit(1)} \" || make install"
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked cross platform for me; it should have been selected as the correct answer.

Comment: You get my vote because of cross platform support.

Comment: While ugly and kind of stupid, this indeed is the best thing I could find after searching for a while. I do wonder though, surely there is some npm package that makes this cleaner.

Comment: Any npm package providing anything like an IIF cli will quickly devolve into similar levels of complexity in your script strings, and will similarly suffer from the nightmare that is the double-encoding of nested strings.
Personally, if I have more than one of these, I create a simple JS file with a switch statement on the first arg, so I can have all my tests in one file, and still leave the `&&` and `||` in the script strings.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add another section in your .json under devDependencies? Then if you do npm install  it'd install the packages specified under devDependincies and npm install --production would install the regular dependcies.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to take a different tack on uglifying your code. Take a look at [connect-browserify](https://github.com/andreypopp/connect-browserify) or the even more powerful [asset-rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack).

These can automatically uglify your code on launch of the Express server, rather than on install. And you can configure them to do different things in development and production.

Comment: From the connect-browserify github page: `You should never use this middleware in production — use nginx for serving pre-built bundles to a browser.`

Comment: Thanks for that correction. Asset Rack is very much designed for use in production, however.